# Feature-Request: Down Vote Pop Up

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, down-votes

What about a little non-binding banner that pops up when someone down-votes saying, "Thanks for the feedback - please take a moment to explain your reasons for down-voting in the comments (optional)." or some such...

Unexplained down-votes leave me with such a hollow feeling.

(Likely this should be migrated to meta.SO - maybe its been asked there - I don't know I'm on a phone connection and can't check.)

Comment: Remember an upvote isn't 10 rep, it's 10 downvotes waiting to be spent ;)

Comment: Sure... Blow out my candle so yours shines brighter. Push me down so you stand taller... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean like this?

[image: downvote popup]

[For the record, I reversed the downvote, it was just to demonstrate the existing popup.]

Comment: Heh -- Ain't that cute... um, yeah... Exactly like that... I guess I haven't down-voted enough to notice... even pops up on my phone. Well that was easy.

Comment: Maybe then what we need is a hand that reaches out of the screen and gives a gentle smack across the face with a glove that says "Are you challenging this question to a duel? Submit your quibble in the comments!"

Comment: Strangely I don't get that.  I thought I remembered getting it, but I don't anymore.  I guess after 60 or so downvotes they give up.

Comment: @RussellSteen Its display logic may have a rep component.

Answer (score -1):

Unexplained downvotes are a bit frustrating sometimes - if I can't see why then I'll usually add a comment asking the downvoter why, and sometimes that gets a message. If not, then pah, one of those things! Nothing worth getting stressed over.